# How do you get the count of svn commits log

Tags: svn

for projects under git controls, I use `git shortlog` to get counts of commits.

currently I am working for a project under svn controls.

How do you get the count of svn commits log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in command until svn version 1.6. You may use `svn log` to create a plain text or xml log file and use a parser to create the statistics.

```
svn log -v --xml http://www.sourceforge.net/svnroot/
```

As an alternative you may use [statsvn](http://www.statsvn.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Subversion projects don't necessarily follow the Git convention of a single summary line followed by the details in the commit message, so you might not be able to get output that is as useful as git shortlog.  This obviously depends on the policies of the project, though.

I think parsing the output of "svn log" to produce something similar to "git shortlog" should be quite easy.

If you just want counts per user, you could try this quick'n'dirty option:

`svn log --xml | grep '<author>' | sed -e 's/<author>\([^<]*\)<\/author>/\1/' | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 0):

Use svn log with grep count argument

From man page, `grep --count -c, --count`

> Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for
>   each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see below),
>   count non-matching lines.

```
svn log -v --xml http://www.sourceforge.net/svnroot/ | grep -c '<author>'
```